# ec2 not accepting inbound traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

So, I've gone through multiple SO threads, but I'm unable to do it.

I launched an ec2 instance and installed ubuntu18.04 to it. I installed nginx on top of it.

Now I'm trying to browse my server IP via browser, but it shows `it can't be reached`. I tried `wget localhost` on shell and it downloads a file with content `If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.`, which means nginx is working fine.

Now, I edited my `Security group` config associated with the instance as follow:-

**Inbound Settings**

[image]

**Outbound Settings**

[image]

But, it's still not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried simply querying it with cURL from the outside?

Comment: What difference would it make?

Comment: cURL gives you tons of information and isn't restricted by quite a lot of things that actually cause problems with browsers.

Answer (score 0):

- Can you please check internal firewall on your instance, it is enabled or not. If not try to disable it and see.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04

- Secondly, have you installed any webserver on EC2, otherwise it may not be able to find anything on localhost. There should be a webserver to listen to request on port 80.

Comment: - Also see if you have started your webserver or not. I doubt either you do have any webserver installed or the web server is not started.

Comment: Firewall is inactive.`sudo ufw status . Status: inactive`

Comment: Isn't nginx a webserver in itself?

Comment: Noobish. I was using the private IP.